# Giving role based on data in a JSON

Tags: python, discord.py

so my problem is. I have a rank/leaderboard bot on my discord(selfcoded). Now I wanna add that who ever is rank 1 should get a role that says *rank 1*. I already created the role and have the ID aswell, but now I have no idea to actually make it happen that my bot sees he has the most xp give him this role, when he lost the pace take it again. Hope u understand what I mean. (Is there anyway I can use my calculate_rank?

My code

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    await update_data(users, member)

    with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot == False:
        with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)

        await update_data(users, message.author)
        await add_experience(users, message.author, 5)
        await level_up(users, message.author, message)
        with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)

    await client.process_commands(message)


async def update_data(users, user):
    if not f'{user.id}' in users:
        users[f'{user.id}'] = {}
        users[f'{user.id}']['xp'] = 0
        users[f'{user.id}']['level'] = 1
        users[f'{user.id}']["last_message"] = 0
        users[f'{user.id}']["name"] = user.name

def calculate_rank(user_xp: int, data: dict=None) -> int:
    if data is None:
        with open("users.json", "r") as f:
            data = json.load(f)

    xp = [value["xp"] for value in data.values()]
    xp.append(user_xp)
    xp.sort(reverse=True)
    return xp.index(user_xp) + 1


async def add_experience(users, user, exp):
    if time.time() - users[f'{user.id}']["last_message"] > 20:
        users[f'{user.id}']['xp'] += random.randint(1, 10)
        users[f'{user.id}']["last_message"] = time.time()
    else:
        return

async def level_up(users, user, message):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as g:
        levels = json.load(g)
    experience = users[f'{user.id}']['xp']
    lvl_start = users[f'{user.id}']['level']
    lvl_end = int(experience ** (1 / 4))
    if lvl_start < lvl_end:
        await message.channel.send(f'{user.mention} ist gerade auf Level {lvl_end} gestiegen!')
        users[f'{user.id}']['level'] = lvl_end

@client.command()
async def rank(ctx, *, member:discord.Member=None):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    if member == None:
        memberID = ctx.author.id
        mentioned = ctx.author.name
    else:
        memberID = member.id
        mentioned = member.name
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)
    xp = users[str(memberID)]['xp']
    lvl = users[str(memberID)]['level']
    rank = calculate_rank(xp)


    embed = discord.Embed(title='')
    embed.add_field(name="Spieler", value=mentioned, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Level:", value=lvl, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Experience:", value=xp, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Rank:", value=rank, inline=True)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@client.command()
async def levels(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    top_spieler = {k: v for k, v in sorted(data.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]["xp"], reverse=True)}

    names = ''
    for position, user in enumerate(top_spieler):
        names += f"{position+1} - <@!{user}> mit Level: {top_spieler[user]['level']} Exp: {top_spieler[user]['xp']}\n"
        embed = discord.Embed(title='')
        embed.add_field(name="Spieler", value=names, inline=False)
        if position+1 > 19:
            break
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the top 1 is the 1 member that has the most experience, you should check everytime you use `add_experience` that the `user` to which you added experience has more than the current top 1. If you consider the top 1 that is the person with the highest level (so the first person to reach that level), you should check each time you `level_up` a user that the level that he now has is bigger than the maximum of the levels of all the other users.

I could provide more details if you provide more details about how your level/user structure is

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. My Leaderboard is structured my experience. So Whoever has the most experience is "rank 1"